# how to insert date value in android?

Tags: android

i am working on data manipulation using sqlite.

how can i insert the datetime value in sqlite

i implemented the below code in my app.

it works,

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String temp=property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
Date s=formatter.parse(temp.substring(5, temp.length()-5));
String pubdate= formatter.format(s);
```

but i cant sort by date Crying or Very sad Crying or Very sad Crying or Very sad Crying or Very sad Crying or Very sad Crying or Very sad

help help help Idea Idea Idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose a different format (e.g., `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`) that is sortable. Or store the date/time as an `INTEGER` milliseconds-since-the-epoch value (see `getTime()` on the `Date` class).